Adjust window transparency and blurriness of a Mac app
How does the Warp terminal Mac app achieve this feature that lets users adjust the amount of transparency and blurriness of the window?
I have tried working with NSVisualEffectView.blendingMode and NSVisualEffectView.material, which does get me the blurry background effect but does not let me adjust how blurry it should be.
Would be nice to have a boolean value from 0.0 to 1.0 which adjusts the blurriness — how can this be achieved? Please see the image for context of how the feature works in the Warp app.
Image of Warp app

There are opacity(_:) and blur(radius:, opaque:) view modifiers.
This is how you can do it:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var customOpacity = 0.75
    @State private var customBlurriness = 0.85
    @State private var isSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 20) { _ in
                Text("But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born ...")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
        .opacity(customOpacity)
        .blur(radius: customBlurriness)
        .onTapGesture {
            isSheet.toggle()
        }
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheet) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Slider(value: $customOpacity) {
                    Text("Opacity \((customOpacity * 100).formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0))))")
                        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                }
                Slider(value: $customBlurriness) {
                    Text("Blur radius \((customBlurriness * 100).formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0))))")
                        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                }
                Button("Ok") {
                    isSheet = false
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.background)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .frame(width: 300)
        }
    }
}

